# Toshiba USB webcam not recognized on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, usb, webcam

I have a Toshiba USB webcam but I can't make it work on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

Here I placed some command outputs that may be useful:

```
$> hwinfo --usb
03: USB 00.2: 11200 TV Card                                     
  [Created at usb.122]
  Unique ID: WiL4.3qstbdAw+R6
  Parent ID: k4bc.2DFUsyrieMD
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.2
  SysFS BusID: 1-2:1.2
  Hardware Class: tv card
  Model: "Pixart Imaging PAC731x Trust Webcam"
  Hotplug: USB
  Vendor: usb 0x093a "Pixart Imaging, Inc."
  Device: usb 0x2621 "PAC731x Trust Webcam"
  Revision: "1.00"
  Driver: "snd-usb-audio"
  Driver Modules: "snd_usb_audio"
  Speed: 12 Mbps
  Module Alias: "usb:v093Ap2621d0100dc00dsc00dp00ic01isc02ip00in02"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: gspca_pac7311 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe gspca_pac7311"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: gspca_pac7302 is active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe gspca_pac7302"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #8 (Hub)
```

```
$> ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2
```

When unplugged the camera, this command only outputs two results.

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so cheese
```

With this last command Cheese recognizes my camera. But when I select it, everything is black.

Two things that may be worth noting:

1. My laptop has an integrated webcam (could them be in conflict with each other?)
2. When the USB camera is plugged in another device it lights a blue LED. On my Ubuntu machine this LED is off.

```
$> LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so fswebcam --device /dev/video2 dd.jpg

--- Opening /dev/video2...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video2 opened.
No input was specified, using the first.
Adjusting resolution from 384x288 to 640x480.
libv4l2: error turning on stream: Protocol error
Error starting stream.
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Protocol error
Unable to use mmap. Using read instead.
--- Capturing frame...
libv4l2: error dequeuing buf: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_DQBUF: Invalid argument
No frames captured.
```

After executing this command `ls /dev/video*` outputs one less entry. Also, Cheese does not recognizes the camera using the third command above. Furthermore, the blue LED stays on. If unplugged behavior goes back as stated in the beginning of the post.

If you would like to see the output of another command, please let me know!